# Case statements in SWITCH statements in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm updating a Google Sheet. In that Google Sheet, I need to display a student's grade based on specific cut offs. I *thought* a [SWITCH statement](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013690?hl=en) would be the correct approach.  However, based on that documentation, it looks like the case statements are mappings instead of conditionals. This seems incorrect. I feel like I'm misunderstanding something. At this time, I have the following `SWITCH` statement.

```
=SWITCH(85, 85<=60, "F", 85<=70, "D", 85<=80, "C", 85<=90, "B", 85<=100, "A", "Unknown")
```

`85` is the value in a cell. I manually put it in to debug. However, this statement always results in "Unknown". Is there a way to use conditional statements in a SWITCH statement?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

What you should actually use is the [IFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145) function instead

```
=IF(LEN(A2),IFS(A2<=60, "F", A2<=70, "D", A2<=80, "C", A2<=90, "B", A2<=100, "A"),"Unknown")
```

Using the extra function [ArrayFormula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en-GB) we apply the same formula to each row for the whole range

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(A2:A), 
    IFS(A2:A<=60, "F", A2:A<=70, "D", A2:A<=80, "C", A2:A<=90, "B", A2:A<=100, "A"),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong function. Use IFS instead.

Your example:

```
=IFS(A1<=60; "F"; A1<=70; "D"; A1<=80; "C"; A1<=90; "B"; A1<=100; "A")
```